# How to implement a custom slice for a Bitvector

Tags: data-structures, rust, boolean, slice

I'm implementing a Bitvector. My question is - How do I implement the slice functionality? Here is my code (things I've tried follow after the code):

```
use core::ops::Range;
use std::ops::Index;

pub struct Bitvec {
    vec: Vec<u8>,
}

impl Bitvec {
    pub fn new(capacity: usize) -> Bitvec {
        Bitvec {
            vec: Vec::with_capacity(capacity),
        }
    }

    pub fn bit_at(&self, index: usize) -> bool {
        let mask = 2u8.pow(7 - (index % 8) as u32);
        self.vec.get(index / 8).unwrap() & mask == mask
    }

    pub fn push(&mut self, val: u8) {
        self.vec.push(val);
    }
}

impl Index<usize> for Bitvec {
    type Output = bool;
    fn index(&self, index: usize) -> &Self::Output {
        match self.bit_at(index) {
            true => &true,
            false => &false,
        }
    }
}

impl Index<Range<usize> for Bitvec {
    type Output = ??;
    fn index(&self, index: Range<usize>) -> &Self::Output {
        //What should go here?
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut bv = Bitvec::new(20);
    bv.push(0b1011_0011);
    assert_eq!(bv.bit_at(0), true);
    assert_eq!(bv.bit_at(1), false);

    assert_eq!(bv[0], true);
    assert_eq!(bv[1], false);

    let slice = bv[2..4]; //should return a slice that represents the two bits of [11]
}
```

What should the impl of Index<Range> for Bitvec return?

Things I've tried:

- Creating a struct BitSlice that holds a start and an end and returning that. I end up fighting with the borrow checker with lifetimes since I need to have the BitSlice hold a reference to the Bitvec. Also can't return an &BitSlice from the index(...) function.
- Having the Bitvec own a BitSlice but that runs into similar issues where the BitSlice and the Bitvec refer to each other
- Having the Bitvec own an Option but also run into issues with lifetimes.

Comment: Interesting question! The only two types that implement range indexing are slices and strings, and they both have magic compiler support that causes `&[]` and `&str` to carry a length as well as a pointer to the start. Without that, you'd have to return some type of your own, but since it has to be a reference, you can't create and return it from `index()`. I'm hoping some more experienced Rustacean will answer this.

Comment: I can implement a get_slice(&self, start:usize, end:usize) on Bitvector that returns a new BitSlice struct and it works that way. But I can't seem to be able to do it using the Index trait. I think I have to implement a smart pointer that holds the underlying vector and then share it between the Bitvector and the BitSlice.

Comment: The Rust subreddit is pretty good: https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/4as7gx/why_make_the_index_trait_so_useless/

Comment: "What should the impl of `Index<Range>` for `Bitvec` return?" Nothing, since you shouldn't have one. `Index` is meant for things that already exist in the data structure and can be referenced, but that isn't possible here since you can't reference bits of the values. You can't just create a `Bitslice` to return, no matter how many smart pointers you use, because you wouldn't know when to drop it.

Comment: Look at something like Rust's built in `VecDeque`, which chose to have methods like [`make_contiguous`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.VecDeque.html#method.make_contiguous) and [`as_slices`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.VecDeque.html#method.as_slices) instead of having an `Index<Range>` since the contiguous slice just doesn't exist in memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slice types like `&str` or `&[u8]` are fat pointers, containing a pointer to some data and a length. The type `&[T]` is syntactic sugar for a struct resembling this:

```
struct Slice<'a, T> {
    data: *const T,
    len: usize,
    _lifetime: PhantomData<&'a T>,
}
```

The caveat is that the ABI is unstable, so you can't make any assumptions about the order of those fields.

A pointer is always to a byte, not a bit, so a fat pointer to a `BitVec` slice would also need to contain a bit offset for where the slice begins within the first byte:

```
pub struct BitSlice<'a> {
    offset: u8,
    len: usize,
    ptr: *const u8,
    _lifetime: PhantomData<&'a u8>,
}
```

You *can* construct one of these, but the `Index::index` trait method returns `&Self::Output`. There is no way to transmute a `BitSlice<'a>` into a `&'a [T]`.

---

It might be possible to shoe-horn the length and offset into a single `usize` and be extremely careful about how that is accessed. [Here's a semi-complete sketch](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5d2f1a0394c7d31faa38f833fb4cfeb0), but there are likely soundness holes in that implementation. Certainly, if you are a Rust beginner, you should not be attempting it!

Comment: I think it does work. The limitiation is on the length of the slice. It's fine for 64 bit systems, but on an 16 bit system, you'd only have 8 bits for the length, which is quite restrictive.